# Liskov principle and Matrix design

Tags: inheritance, matrix, liskov-substitution-principle

I'm trying to design following classess: Matrix and SquareMatrix. Both of them will be able to do basic matrix operations and SquareMatrix will additionaly be able to check if it is diagonal. So, I was thinking of creating the Matrix class and then have SquareMatrix inherit from it. Is it a good idea considering Liskov principle? Because at first it seems like the basic violation with square and rectangle but when I think about it I cant find any reason why it would be a bad idea. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. For me, you only need one class, as SquareMatrix is just a different configuration for the more general Matrix. If anything a diagonal only matrix may warrant a specialization class, not a square matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If `SquareMatrix` just adds one extra method to check whether it is diagonal, and all other methods can remain exactly as they where, then it might be OK. Adding methods in a subclass to an inherited class is generally compatible with LSP.

But most likely, you would also want to insist that the matrix is, in fact, square. So if your original `Matrix` class has functionality to change the height or the width of the matrix, you would have to somehow 'disable' this functionality in the `SquareMatrix` subclass. And such disabling is incompatible with LSP.

If you wish to have a separate `SquareMatrix` class, then the normal route would be a `MatrixInterface` with an API that all matrices have in common, an `AbstractMatrix` providing a basic implementation of this interface, a `ResizableMatrix` for matrices of which the dimensions can change, and a `SquareMatrix` with height and width guaranteed to be equal -- where the latter two both inherit from the `AbstractMatrix`.

If this is overly complex for your use case, a cleaner solution might be to add two methods to your `Matrix` class: `isSquare`, which returns whether or not a matrix is square, and `isDiagonal`, which under the assumption (precondition) that the matrix is square returns whether the matrix also diagonal.